# Problem in WiFi network scaninng in every second in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to scan available wifi network through my Android device. Here's the chunk of code -

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults(); 

                        //int newRSSI= intent.getIntExtra(wifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_RSSI, 0);
                        //WifiDistance wifi_dis = new WifiDistance();

                        for (ScanResult result : results) {

                            textView.append("\nSSID="+result.SSID + ", " + "Strength(dBm)=" + result.level + ", AP: "+ result.BSSID);
                            wifi+="\n"+result.SSID + ", " + result.level + ", "+ result.BSSID;


                            //WifiDistance.getWifiDistance().distanceCalc(result.BSSID, result.level);
                    }, 
                    new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

                    // Initiate a scan.
                wifiManager.startScan();

                }
```

I have put this under a action handler such as if a button is pressed it starts scanning. Now my problem is, when my phone is connected to a specific network it does not update the wifi scanning result automatically. It just stays with the older data. I want to press the button to start scanning and update the scan result every second.

I'm using OS 2.1 in HTC Magic.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly how do you attempt to update the scan results every second?

it looks to me as you only update the list whenever a broadcast is received, and the startscan code appears after the List population.

Instead you could could use a timer task to update run a seperate method which updates the Scanresult list every second, and run the For-Loop again.

something like:

```
Public void RunEverySecond(){
List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

for (ScanResult result : results) {

                        textView.append("\nSSID="+result.SSID + ", " + "Strength(dBm)=" + result.level + ", AP: "+ result.BSSID);
                        wifi+="\n"+result.SSID + ", " + result.level + ", "+ result.BSSID;

                }
}
```

maybe?

Comment: Thanks ... Instead of using loop I just created a thread using the timer. Looking at your time option it came into my mind and it worked. Thanks a lot :).